# Split source code: ListView for phones / GridView for tablet

Tags: android

I want two different layouts for my app: one for phones and one for tablets.

In a `Fragment` I'll use a `ListView` for phones and a `GridView` for tablets.

I know that I can set specific layouts according to the screen size, but how can I split the source code according to which layout is used?

Comment: Try: [Building a Dynamic UI with Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `layout-large` folder in same level than `layout` folder, with layout specific for tablets.

Just add in your `layout-large`, add an XML file that has the same name that the one in your `layout_folder`, and put in it the XML code for tablets (and layout specific for phones in `layout` folder).

You will find more informations on [Supporting different screen size](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

Then, you may want in your code to adapt layout like :

```
int screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;

switch(screenSize) {
    case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE:
        // Set adapter for GridView
        break;
    default:
        // Set adapter for ListView
}
```

**Update 2014**

As stated in the link provided,

> Note: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), these size groups are
>   deprecated in favor of a new technique for managing screen sizes based
>   on the available screen width. If you're developing for Android 3.2
>   and greater, see [Declaring Tablet Layouts for Android 3.2](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts) for more
>   information.

Answer (score 2):

You can create 2 Fragments: one with list and one with grid. Both of them will have specific code and if needed their own menu.

The only check you have to do is at runtime, when you have to launch one of them:

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().smallestScreenWidthDp >= 600) {
   // It's a tablet
} else {
   // It's not a tablet
}
```

That's what i do on my code, because i need to know wih menu to inflate. Hope this help.